# ansible debug msg throws error inside handler

Tags: linux, ansible, devops, ansible-2.x, ansible-handlers

Playbook runs fine but debug msg module throws undefined variable error.

```
---
- hosts: labservers
 become: yes
 tasks:
- name: restart httpd
 service:
     name: httpd
     state: restarted
 notify:
     - cmds
 handlers:
- name: change file details
replace:
    path: /etc/httpd/conf/magic
    regexp: 'its is nothing'
    replace: '100 notes ashes'
register: httpd_data
- name: commands out
debug:
    msg: "{{httpd_data}}"
listen: "cmds"
```

[code in image for clear understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3j2eH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by calling both the tasks in handlers using listen.

```
---
- hosts: labservers
become: yes
tasks:
- name: restart httpd
service:
     name: httpd
     state: restarted
notify:
     - cmds
handlers:
- name: change file details
replace:
    path: /etc/httpd/conf/magic
    regexp: '100 notes ashes'
    replace: '100 akash'
register: httpd_data
listen: "cmds"
- name: debug details
debug:
     msg:"{{ httpd_data }}"
listen: "cmds"
```